# Did a RTC solar tracker need any photosensor?

Tags: solar-energy

I planned to do a solar tracker for my project and I am going to make a RTC solar tracker(actually still considering). So, do I still need photosensor like LDR for tracking the sun?

Answer (score 1):

Do not put a photosensor or sun-finder on your array.  Your real-time clock may use the astronomy algorithms provided by Sandia National Lab to be very certain about where the sun is at any given time.  (See link below)

Please install a GPS, however, so that your time will be accurate as well as your exact location on the Earth's surface.

Find out how much performance your solar panels lose when they're off by a few degrees--- allowing some error could save motor energy.

Also, check shading row-to-row.  If there's shading, your perfect sun-tracking won't actually be helping during sunrise and sunset.

https://pvpmc.sandia.gov/modeling-steps/1-weather-design-inputs/sun-position/solar-position-algorithm-spa/

Answer (score 0):

People building solar trackers are common, as a financial gain : not really, but as a project fun : great if you are the tinkering type.

Two examples below, and the one I hoped to find used two small (3 inch sq) pv panels with a jar of water as a lens to drive a small motor in either direction...

[tracker 1](http://www.mdpub.com/suntracker/)

[tracker 2](https://www.motherearthnews.com/diy/solar-tracker-zmaz77ndzgoe)